# Which packages required for generic ubuntu 16.04 installation?

Tags: ubuntu, cobbler

I want to configure cobbler for Ubuntu 16.04 installation, run cobbler reposync which calls command like

```
/usr/bin/debmirror --nocleanup --verbose --ignore-release-gpg --method=http --host=archive.ubuntu.com --root=/ubuntu --dist=xenial,xenial-updates,xenial-security --section=main,universe /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/ubuntu-16.04-x86_64 --nosource -a amd64
```

there are to many packages. much of them i will never use
The main problem that I am required to move it between servers, and I'm looking for way for don't copy this 20G.

Which the simplest way for gathering list of packages which requirement for generic Ubuntu 16.04 installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get all requirement packages for installation the copy packages from installation disk ^)

I didn't figure out how to decrease number of packages which downloaded which cobbler's repo creating, so I just created local repo and added into it a couple of mine packages.

```
  so,  for offline ubuntu installation:
     1. copy packages from installation ISO
     2. add your additional packages
     3. create your local repo
     4. add your repo in cobbler snippets ( preseed file)  for using it during installation
```